# Maclaurin series for $f(x) =\pi x^8 e^{-x^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Find the Maclaurin series for:
$$f(x) =\pi x^8 e^{-x^3}$$
What I have :
$e^x = $ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n\over n!}$
THEREFORE $x^8 e^{-x^3}= $ $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {-x^{3n+8}\over n!}$$
Now I don't know how the pi comes into play, do I just multiply it to the equation so f(x)=
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {-\pi x^{3n+8}\over n!}$$
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You wrote $\displaystyle \pi x^8{e^{-x}}^3$, coded as \pi x^8{e^{-x}}^3.  Did you mean $\pi x^8(e^{-x})^3$ or did you perhaps mean $\pi x^8 e^{-x^3}$?  Your way of coding it doesn't make sense either way, but both that and your proposed answer suggest the latter meaning. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes it was the latter, I was having difficulty making the equation appear properly. Sorry bout that

Comment: I've changed it to $e^{-x^3}$, coded as e^{-x^3}. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark: There should be
$$
x^8 e^{-3x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x^3)^n\cdot x^8}{n!},
$$
hence the final answer is 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \pi(-1)^n\frac{x^{3n+8}}{n!}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why is pi being multiplied to $(-1)^n$?

Comment: @ricefieldboy $\pi$ a multiplying constant. The first series is for $g(x)=x^8e^{-3x}$, the second one for $f(x)=\pi g(x)$.

Comment: Doesn't $\pi(-1)^n$ make the equation alternate between negative and positive? Unless that is how it should be.

Comment: @ricefieldboy It is from $(-x^3)^n=(-1)^n\cdot(x^3)^n=(-1)^n x^{3n}$ (if I understand your question).

Answer (score 1):

You're largely on the right track, provided you clarify according to my comment under the question, but one thing is wrong with your proposed answer: the minus sign needs to be part of what is raised to a power, thus you need $(-x)^\text{some exponent}$ rather than $-x^\text{some exponent}$, which would mean $-\left( x^\text{some exponent} \right)$.